# How "strong" are the standard passwords by pwgen?

Tags: linux, passwords

I'm trying to determine how many different "easy to remember" 8 character passwords can the [pwgen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pwgen) tool create?  Unfortunately, I did not find this information, either on the manpage or on the "official" Sourceforge site.

pwgen generates (by default) passwords containing numbers, upper- and lowercase letters with length 8. If every combination of those was allowed, that would be 62^8 possible outcomes.

But pwgen will not just generate a random password, but a "pronounceable" one. This limits the number of possible outcomes, i.e., there are now less than 62^8 passwords that pwgen can generate.  I am trying to determine how many possible outcomes does the generation process of pwgen have in "pronounceable" password mode (which is the default one).

Note: I do not ask for any hard calculations here.  Rather, the rules that pwgen follows (what character combinations/sequences it either allows or excludes).  I am aware that SU is not a calculation service; deriving the actual number of possible passwords from the rules can be left for the reader or a more appropriate community.

Comment: Is your question what are the character combinations/sequences allowed (or excluded), by pwgen, or how many permutations does that create?  The first one is probably on-topic.  The seond is a math question that probably wouldn't be on-topic.

Comment: @fixer1234 The first one would be enough, I can math that out on my own then. Will update the question.

Comment: [This answer on Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/72822/68614) may be helpful.